# Authorizing Google API using stored refresh token and iDataStore in VB.NET

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am developing an integration with Google Calender from a vb.net web application. So far I understand that I need my own implementation of `iDataStore` as I will be storing refresh tokens belonging to different users on my website with the view to connect to their calendar later and add events.

Here's my code for creating a new authorised user:

```
        Dim clientSecrets As New ClientSecrets
        clientSecrets.ClientId = "MyClientID"
        clientSecrets.ClientSecret = "MyClientSecret"

        Dim input() As String = {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"}
        Dim scope As New List(Of String)(input)    

        Dim myStoredResponse As New GoogleOauthAPI.StoredResponse(txtrefreshToken.Text)
        Dim savedDataStoreObj As New GoogleOauthAPI.SavedDataStore(myStoredResponse)

        Dim credential As UserCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(clientSecrets, scope, "user", Threading.CancellationToken.None, savedDataStoreObj).Result
```

I am getting the following error when attempting to create the `UserCredential` object:

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: task
```

The GoogleOauthAPI.StoredResponse was based on the [following guide](http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/#Loading_Stored_refresh-Token) but converted from C# to vb.net. I had some uncertainty as to whether the conversion of the code was done correctly.

[Here is the original C# class](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13606144/code/SavedDataStore.txt)

[and here is the class converted to vb](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13606144/code/vbConvertedClass.txt)

When the `myStoredResponse` object is created I can inspect it in debug mode and it looks like it's pulling in the refresh code, I'm just uncertain why the user credentials cannot be created and throws this error?

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem in the end. When converting the iDataStore interface class from C# to VB.net I did not have the `Implements IDataStore.MethodName` appended to each function.

[Here is my revised iDataStore VB class](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13606144/code/iDataStoreVB.txt), feel free to use this in your own projects.